# sql query to combin results from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table **Customers** (id,name) **Phones** (id,customerId,phoneType,phone)
is it posssible to write a query that return row like this:

CustomerId, CustomerName, Phone1, Phone2, Mobile1, Mobile2

Phone1,Phone2,Mobile1,Mobile2 are phone types

i tried

```
select id as CustomerId, name as CustomerName, phone as Phone1
from Customers, Phones
where Customers.id = Phones.customerId and 
Phones.phoneType = N'Phone1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
select *
from (select id as customerid, name as customername, phonetype, phone
     from customers inner join phones on customers.id = phones.customerid
) src
pivot
(max(phone) for phonetype in ([phone1],[phone2],[mobile1],[mobile2])) p
```

Comment: thanks it's working now but i needed to set sp_dbcmptlevel to 90, is there any problem with this?
and if i want to ([phone1] or [PH1]) is it prossible??

Comment: That will work on a 2005 database, yes. You can rename the result columns as you normally would.